# How to add a POST request for all inputs in PDO PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following PHP PDO Update script, instead of having the inputs all hardcoded I would like to get the values from POST.

How can I modify the following script to update both name and link to POST input values?

```
 <?php
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'tests';
$userdb = 'username';
$passdb = 'password';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

  // changes data in "name" si "link" columns, where id=3
  $sql = "UPDATE `sites` SET `name`='Spanish Course', `link`='marplo.net/spaniola' WHERE `id`=3";
  $count = $conn->exec($sql);

  $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

// If the query is succesfully performed ($count not false)
if($count !== false) echo 'Affected rows : '. $count;       // Shows the number of affected rows
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the hard-coded values with dynamic values coming from `$_POST` you can use prepared statements. First you need to make sure with `isset` that the values were sent to your script. Then you should prepared the SQL statement with placeholders and execute passing in the array with your data.

This sample script shows how it could be done:

```
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'tests';
$userdb = 'username';
$passdb = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8'; // you should be using utf8mb4 instead

if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['id'])) {
    // Connect and create the PDO object
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=$charset", $userdb, $passdb, $options);

    // changes data in "name" si "link" columns, where id=3
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `sites` SET `name`=:name, `link`=:link WHERE `id`=:id');
    $stmt->execute([
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'link' => $_POST['link'],
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
    ]);

    // Shows the number of affected rows
    echo 'Affected rows : '. $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

If you are unsure about the correct use of PDO you can take a look at this well-acclaimed PDO guide https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `POST['']` properties to get the information from a [POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) request.

```
<?php
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'tests';
$userdb = 'username';
$passdb = 'password';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb; charset=utf8", $userdb, $passdb);

  // changes data in "name" is "link" columns, where id=3
  $sql = "UPDATE `sites` SET `name`=':name', `link`=':link' WHERE `id`=3";
  $conn->prepare($sql);
  $count = $conn->exec(array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'link' => $_POST['link']));
  $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

// If the query is succesfully performed ($count not false)
if($count !== false) echo 'Affected rows : '. $count;       // Shows the number of affected rows
?>
```

**Notice** that I used the prepared query statement. This provides protection from [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: Will this protect my db from most sql injection?

Comment: Does PDO itself also add some protection?

Comment: @shn I keep getting the error undefined method PDO for this line: `$count = $conn->execute(array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'link' => $_POST['link']));`

Comment: You may be using a different version of PDO, check how to get the information out of the PDO after executing. There are different methods based on how you want the information from the query.

Comment: Please remove that mention of `addslashes`, it helps with nothing and is totally misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how to get the information out of the PDO after executing". I just need the record to update once the parameters are met

Comment: I can't seem to find anything I could change

Comment: Previous versions of PDO use `execute()`, try using `exec()` since that is what you used before.

Comment: That helped that issue but now I get: `Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: I can't help you with this issue because the PHP/PDO version is different than the current. Also the `execute()` and `exec()` functions are different. Use this resource to figure it out: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php