# How can I prevent SQL from being executed until POST values are not empty?

Tags: php, sql

I have the following PHP script that executes an sql update query, how can I prevent it from being executed until the two POST values are not empty?

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $delivery_time = addslashes($_POST['delivery_time']);
    $customer = addslashes($_POST['customer']);

    $sql = "UPDATE Equipment SET time = '$time', customer = '$customer' WHERE status ='Broken' ";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Comment: Um, by adding validation that checks for null values and blocks it until they are not?

Comment: Please read about **[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use **[prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** with **[bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**. See **[this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases)** and **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** for some good examples.

Comment: Ohh, I read the question wrong again... anyway you should prevent SQL injection in the first place.

Comment: Wrap all the code in `if(!empty($_POST['delivery_time']) && !empty($_POST['customer']))`

Comment: I have tried to prevent sql injection using PDO, this was my initial post but I kept running into errors using the answer given, If someone can please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690184/how-to-add-a-post-request-for-all-inputs-in-pdo-php/56690265#56690265

Comment: No wonder, that answer was pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

To avoid sending the query until `$_POST` variables are supplied check for their existence with `if` statement and `isset`.

```
if (isset($_POST['delivery_time'], $_POST['customer'])) {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); // switch off emulated prepares, but you should add charset=utf8mb4 in the contructor above too

    $sql = "UPDATE Equipment SET `time` = ?, `customer` = ? WHERE `status` ='Broken' ";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute([
        $_POST['delivery_time'],
        $_POST['customer']
    ]);

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}
```